# how would I restrict some parameters without messing with the whole gradient descent algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, constraints, gradient-descent

In a gradient descent case i have many  parameters that get updated each run, for 3 of those these condition have to hold.
1. (a,b,c) >0
2. a+b+.5c<=1

I apply a gradient descent variant with armijo rule for finding the stepsize parameter. Since some parameters have to fall into an constraint set, otherwise the objective function wont work,  either:

1. s gets so small until they fall into that set although the other parameters become unnessecary small.
2. I use two different step size parameters
3. I somehow standardise? the constrainted parameters

the algorithm goes along these lines

1. y
2. gradient(y) (conditions have to hold)
3. gradient setp: y-s* gradient
4. check for the armijo rule (conditions have to hold)
5. proximal operator (conditions have to hold)

how would I handle this correctly, is there a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with the second condition changing to `a + b + c/2 < 1`, here is a straightforward though somewhat messy solution.

[Logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) uses [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) to turn the real line into the interval from 0 to 1. It is defined by `logit(x) = ln(x/(1-x))`.

Similarly, you can determine your three parameters from 3 new parameters with the following rules.

```
a + b + c/2 = logit(u)
a / (a + b + c/2) = logit(v)
b / (b + c/2) = logit(w)
```

The calculation is a bit messy, but you can do gradient descent to determine te correct values for `u`, `v`, and `w`. Which will then give you `a`, `b`, and `c`. Be warned that it is also computationally somewhat expensive. This is why machine learning uses `relu` whenever possible, and only uses `logit` where needed to get a probability out.